# INI editing with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, path, ini

My problem is I want to change paths in INI Files which are saved in a folder and its subfolders.

The path of the folder is `C:\New\Path\`.

Example INI file:

```
notAIniText = C:\A\Path\notAIniText
maybeAIniText = C:\A\Path\maybeAIniText
AIniText = C:\A\Path\AIniText
```

I read some other questions about PSini but I don't want to just id because I want to use the script on multiple PC and I don't want to install every time PSIni.

I tried:

```cs
$mabyIni = "C:\New\Path"
$AiniFile = Get-ChildItem - Path "C:\New\Path\*" -Include *.ini -Recurse
foreach ($file in $AiniFile) {
    Select-String -Path $file -AllMatches "C:\A\Path\" | ForEach-Opject {
        $file -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'), ('$mabyIni')
    } | Set-Content $mabyIni -Include *.ini
```

But this doesn't work. I tried it with `Get-Content` too, but that also doesn't work.

Is there any way without PSini?

Comment: It should search in the ini file the Path and 
replace it with the new. I tried also:            $mabyIni = "C:\New\Path"
    $AiniFile = Get-ChildItem - Path "C:\New\Path\*" -include *.ini -recurse
    ForEach($file in $AiniFile)
    {
         (Get-Content $AiniFile.PSPath) |
         ForEach-Opject {$file -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'),('$mabyIni') }|
    Set-Content $mabyIni -include *.ini

Comment: You should update your question, and not post a comment. The code in your comment is really hard to read. Regardless, I see the issue with the code in your comment, and I'll write up an answer as to why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your comment is close, but just has a few syntax issues. It starts out strong:

```
$mabyIni = "C:\New\Path" 
$AiniFile = Get-ChildItem - Path "C:\New\Path*" -include *.ini -recurse 
ForEach($file in $AiniFile) {
```

So far, so good. You define the new path, and you get a list of .ini files in the old path, then you start to loop through those files. This is all good code so far. Then things start to go astray.

I see that you are trying to get the contents of each .ini file, replace the string in question, and then output that file to the new path with this:

```
    (Get-Content $AiniFile.PSPath) | ForEach-Object {
        $file -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'),('$mabyIni') 
    }| Set-Content $mabyIni -include *.ini
```

Unfortunately you're using the wrong variables, and adding in an extra `ForEach` loop in there as well. Let's start with the `Get-Content` line. At this point in the script you are looping through files, with each current file being represented by `$file`. So what you really want to get the contents of is `$file`, and not `$AiniFile.PSPath`.

```
    (Get-Content $file)
```

Ok, that got us the contents of that file as an array of strings. Now, I'm guessing you weren't aware, but the `-Replace` operator works on arrays of strings. Perfect, we just so happen to have gotten an array of strings! Since the `Get-Content` command is wrapped in parenthesis it completes first, we can actually just tack on the `-Replace` command right after it.

```
    (Get-Content $file) -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'),$mabyIni
```

Your `-replace` command that you had was super close! In fact, I have to give you props for using `[regex]::escape()` in there. That's totally a pro move, well done! The only issue with it is the replacement string didn't need to be in parenthesis, and it was single quoted, so it would not have expanded the string and your .ini files would have all had a line like:

```
AIniText = $mabyIni\AIniText
```

Not exactly what you wanted I'm guessing, so I removed the parenthesis (they weren't hurting anything, but weren't helping either, so for cleanliness and simplicity I got rid of them), and I got rid of the single quotes `'` as well since we really just want the string that's stored in that variable.

So now we're looping through files, reading the contents, replacing the old path with the new path, all that's left is to output the new .ini file. It looks like they're already in place, so we just use the existing path for the file, and set the content to the updated data.

```
    (Get-Content $file) -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'),$mabyIni | Set-Content -Path $File.FullName
```

Ok, done! You just have to close the `ForEach` loop, and run it.

```
$mabyIni = "C:\New\Path" 
$AiniFile = Get-ChildItem - Path "C:\New\Path*" -include *.ini -recurse 
ForEach($file in $AiniFile) { 
    (Get-Content $file) -replace [regex]:Escape('C:\A\Path'),$mabyIni | Set-Content -Path $File.FullName
}
```